# Strengthening of Suslin's rigidity argument?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves, algebraic-k-theory

To fix the situation, let $k$ be an algebraically closed field, and let $C$ be a smooth projective curve over $k$. Suslin's rigidity argument implies in particular that any class in $K_i(k(C),\mathbb{Z}/\ell)$ becomes constant (i.e. lies in the image of $K_i(k,\mathbb{Z}/\ell)$) over the algebraic closure $\overline{k(C)}$, for any $i$ and any prime $\ell$ different from the characteristic of $k$.

I was wondering if the following stronger assertion can be true: consider a class in $K_i(k(C),\mathbb{Z}/\ell)$, which actually comes from $K_i(C,\mathbb{Z}/\ell)$. Is it true that the class becomes constant in $K_i(L,\mathbb{Z}/\ell)$, where $L$ is the maximal unramified extension of $k(C)$? Reformulated, this says that unramified elements of $K_i(k(C),\mathbb{Z}/\ell)$ become constant after suitable unramified extensions.

Now this may very well be a red herring. I would appreciate any counterexamples of classes in the K-theory of curves whose behaviour is different from the description above. I would  appreciate even more any philosophical explanations, either why the above can not be true, or why it might be true. Any comments on situations more general than curves over algebraically closed fields are also most welcome.

[Added later:] I have found two potential reasons for believing the above strengthening:

1. There is a paper of Coombes "On K-theory of curves over finite fields" JPAA 51 (1988), 79-87 which provides some (partly conjectural) calculations of K-theory of curves: for a smooth projective curve $C$ over $k=\overline{\mathbb{F}_q}$, we have 
   $$K_{2n+1}(C)\cong K_{2n+1}(k)\oplus K_{2n+1}(k)$$
   $$K_{2n}(C)\cong\operatorname{Tor}(\operatorname{Jac}_C(k),K_{2n-1}(k)),$$
   where the first statement is unconditional, the second conjectural (but maybe resolved in the meantime?). In this case, the above strengthening seems in fact to be true - the even K-theory with $\ell$-coefficients can be killed by isogenies of the Jacobian, i.e., by unramified (even abelian) covers of the curve $C$. Interpreting the above formulae as coming from the decomposition of the motive $M(C)\cong\mathbb{Z}\oplus\operatorname{Jac}_C\oplus\mathbb{Z}(1)[2]$, maybe a version of the above holds for arbitrary algebraically closed fields?
2. If K-theory with $\ell$-coefficients is controlled by étale topology, then it should be possible to show that classes become trivial over the maximal unramified extension which corresponds to the universal covering of the curve. In arithmetic situations, the Quillen-Lichtenbaum conjecture says something like that. Is it also true for curves over algebraically closed fields that there is a spectral sequence from étale cohomology to algebraic K-theory ($\ell$-coefficients or suitably completed at $\ell$, with $\ell$ different from the characteristic), i.e., that étale and algebraic K-theory coincide?

Comment: Certainly, etale and algebraic K-theory do not coincide. One may say that algebraic K-theory is controlled by motivic cohomology. Also, it seems that the 'usual' method for proving rigidity does not yield any statement as desired.

Comment: @MikhailBondarko: I am not sure about your "certainly". There are cases, like in the Quillen-Lichtenbaum conjecture, where etale and algebraic K-theory (with finite coefficients, maybe completed etc) coincide. Also, etale K-theory is controlled by etale cohomology, and there are situations where etale and motivic cohomology with finite coefficients coincide, see the work of Suslin and Voevodsky. I agree that the usual method of proof does not directly give the strengthening, hence my question.

Comment: Yes, in a certain range \'etale and motivic cohomology groups are isomorphic. Could you say, what are the (numbers of the) groups you are interested in? Also, do you have any more evidence supporting your conjecture?

Comment: @MikhailBondarko: I would not call it conjecture, I have some philosophical positive evidence but it can still go either way. I also do not have any more evidence other than what is written in the question. Therefore, I am not specifically interested in a particular group - I would be interested in any examples of behaviour of K-theory classes under unramified extensions.

Comment: I am curious about an $i=2$ analogue: is it true that every unramified Brauer class is constant after a suitable unramified extension?